# sql query in MS ACCESS, joins and tables from other dbs

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to query a table from a different database and `left join` the result with a linked table I have in my DB.
This is the working part

```sql
SELECT * FROM DbandDetails
IN 'G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb'
WHERE(DbandDetails.Month = 10);
```

Now I am trying to left join the result of this query with the Linked table I have created so I have tried

```sql
SELECT * FROM DbandDetails
IN 'G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb'
WHERE(DbandDetails.Month = 10)
LEFT JOIN Mylinkedtable ON DbandDetails.code = Mylinkedtable.code;
```

As you might have guessed...it does not work...

Comment: You should switch the `join` and the `where` around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That pattern ... `FROM DbandDetails IN 'G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb'` ... can work for a query with a single data source.  However, it breaks when you then try to include additional data sources.  And it doesn't seem to matter whether the additional data sources are located in the current or remote database.

For a query like yours, I find it easier to prefix the table name with the bracketed database path like this: `FROM [G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb].DbandDetails`

I think you should also reposition the `WHERE` clause as [HoneyBadger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587819/honeybadger) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286370/sql-query-in-ms-access-joins-and-tables-from-other-dbs#comment56314204_34286370) ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    [G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb].DbandDetails
    LEFT JOIN Mylinkedtable
    ON DbandDetails.code = Mylinkedtable.code
WHERE DbandDetails.Month = 10;
```

In case you encounter another error, here is the tested query I used as my guide when modifying yours ...

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    [C:\share\Access\Contacts.accdb].Settings
    LEFT JOIN Dual
    ON Settings.ID = Dual.id
WHERE Settings.ID=1;
```

Comment: Wish I could give the answer to both :(

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, the following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM DbandDetails
IN 'G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb'
LEFT JOIN Mylinkedtable ON DbandDetails.code = Mylinkedtable.code
WHERE(DbandDetails.Month = 10);
```

**Edit**

Not being very familiar with MS Access syntax, I'm having to guess here. But could you try:

```
SELECT * FROM DbandDetails
LEFT JOIN Mylinkedtable ON DbandDetails.code = Mylinkedtable.code
IN 'G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb'
WHERE(DbandDetails.Month = 10);
```

**Further edit**

Apparently this solution doesn't work to join a table in a database and a table in a file. Another solution might be:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (
            SELECT * FROM DbandDetails
            IN 'G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb'
         ) DbandDetails
LEFT JOIN Mylinkedtable ON DbandDetails.code = Mylinkedtable.code
WHERE(DbandDetails.Month = 10);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try in a few minutes and let you know!

Comment: Now it says "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find input table or query Mylinkedtable"
The table is there and spelled correctly, could it be that now it expects the table to be in 'G:\allpathtomyfolder\Db.accdb'?

Comment: Yeah, I think it does. Maybe you can first get the results from the file query into a (temp) table, and use that in your `join` query. But like I said in the edit, I'm just guessing here, educated guess, but still a guess

Comment: I'll givi it a try with the temp table

Comment: Let me know how you get on